# Help with mod-rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite urls to site media (images, js, css) like this:
`/folder1/css/css.css` to `/www/folder1/css/css.css`
`/folder2/img/image.jpg` to `/www/folder2/img/image.jpg`

I have a set of folders that contain these files, so it would be nice not to list all those folders, and have a universal rule. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/(?:css|img)/.*)$ /www/$1
```

You must make sure that all your images/css are on `<folder>/css/<filename>` or `<folder>/img/<filename>`. Each URL containing `.../css/...` or `.../img/...` will be prefixed a `/www`.